# What modifications can you make to n to form a subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am currently learning limits of sequences and subsequences in Real Analysis and am unclear on whether certain direct transformations of ***n*** will produce a subsequence.
One problem where this has come up is: *determine the limit of the sequence* **(1+(2/*n*))^*n*** ... I thought I could answer by restructuring to form a subsequence of **(1+(1/*n*))^*n***, which converges to ***e***, so I algebraically modified the sequence to get **[1+(1/(*n*/2))]^(*n*/2)]^2** ... but it seems to me replacing ***n*** with **(*n*/2)** doesn't constitute a subsequence because odd values of ***n*** divided by **2** won't belong to the natural numbers, so you won't index elements of the subsequence for odd ***n*** to elements of the sequence.
I'm also questioning whether on a similar problem, you could substitute n for a value like **n^(1/2)** or ***n*^(5/3)**, since, again, roots of natural numbers and natural numbers raised to non-natural exponents do not always produce natural numbers. Therefore, it seems none of these approaches will produce a subsequence. Is this accurate? To construct a subsequence, are the only permitted direct transformations of ***n*** multiplication, addition, subtraction, or raising ***n*** to the power of a natural number greater **1**? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at every other element of the sequence (starting with the second)
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{1}\right)^1 ,
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{2}\right)^2 ,
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{3}\right)^3 ,
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{4}\right)^4 ,
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{5}\right)^5 ,
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{6}\right)^6 ,
\ldots
$$
you see the subsequence
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{1}\right)^2 ,
\left(\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 ,
\left(\left( 1 + \frac{1}{3}\right)^3\right)^2 ,
\left(\left( 1 + \frac{1}{4}\right)^4\right)^2 ,
\left(\left( 1 + \frac{1}{5}\right)^5\right)^2 ,\ldots
$$
That subsequence clearly converges to $e^2$.

If you know or show that the orginal sequence is monotonic then its   limit must be $e^2$ too.

One moral of the story: you often see more by writing out the first few terms of a sequence or a sum than you do if you try to manipulate the terms with formal "algebraic modifications". (As an instructor I would much rather read this kind of argument. It's much clearer than the seemingly more formal one.)